# How to get exact value of entity in WIT?

Tags: wit.ai

I have an entity with search strategy **free-text** and **keyword**.

My problem is after I trained the entity for a while and give Wit a new expression with **similar value** entity, Wit correctly determine the entity, but **the value is wrong**. Wit automatically infer that the value is synonym of value that is already existed.

In my case, I use it to train a special type of number (I use my native language which still in Beta), let say entity X.

I have trained the entity with value **083333333333**.
When there is a new expression contains similar value **081333333333**, Wit correctly determine the entity as X, but the value is **083333333333** **NOT 081333333333**.
Could Wit detect the entity using its actual value, which is **081333333333**?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON response should look similar like below.

```
{
  "msg_id" : "0566xxxxx85ee-e9a734637880",
  "**_text**" : "081333333333",
  "entities" : {
    "intent" : [ {
      "confidence" : 0.9850458513785204,
      "value" : "083333333333"
    } ]
  }
}
```

If you get the **response._text** on your server-side code you can get the actual text from wit.ai .

Also the usage of value within the wit.ai NLP is somewhat similar to this:

**User**:I am not happy today Mr. Bot.

**Bot:**(Knows that user not happy, responds accordingly) Wow Mr. User, I am sorry to hear that. How can I help you ?

In this above conversation, bot firstly knows that this is the "emotional_state" intent. But after that from the **not happy** keyword he can immediately assigns the **value** of "emotional_state" intended user message to **negative**.

Hope it helps and give you some idea!